# MissingMemberException: 'Guid' object has no attribute 'length'

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, grasshopper, rhino3d

I am trying to get the length of a curve but I am getting the message: `MissingMemberException: 'Guid' object has no attribute 'length'` The same script in C# works perfectly. What is the problem with the python translation? Here is the [Documentation](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/ironpython/functions/curvelength.htm).

**PYTHON:**

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

ln = rs.AddLine(pt1, pt2)

a = ln 
b = ln.Length
```

**C#:**

```
Line ln;

ln = new Line(pt1, pt2);

A = ln;
B = ln.Length;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a quick look at the [documentation](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/ironpython/functions/curvelength.htm). I think you should use `rhinoscriptsyntax.CurveLength`. `AddLine` returns a Guid rather than a curve object. You can pass the Guid to `CurveLength`.

```
rs.CurveLength(ln)
```

Comment: I was just about to post this. Clearly what's being returned is the GUID of the new line, not the line itself.

Comment: Thanks it works, what if I change to the following code:
`import Rhino as Rhino
ln =Rhino.Geometry.Line(pt1,pt2)
a = ln
b = ln.Length`
In this case I get the following error message:
`(ArgumentTypeException): expected Point3d, got Guid`
Why do I also get a GUID in this case and not the line itself?

Comment: The error is `ArgumentTypeException`, so I think this is saying that at least one of the arguments `pt1` and `pt2` is a Guid rather than a `Point3d` object. The exception traceback should tell you on which line of code the error occured.